# I want show a value from ViewModel to Textview in a fragment. Help me to do this

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, retrofit, android-databinding

I want show "answerText.value" from MainViewModel to TextView in a fragment.

MainViewModel:

```
package com.example.intelligenttalkie

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import org.json.JSONObject
import retrofit2.*
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var answerText: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    private lateinit var editText: EditText

    companion object {
        fun onGenerateButtonClick(mainViewModel: MainViewModel, editText: EditText) {

            mainViewModel.editText = editText
            // Get the user's question from the EditText
            val question = mainViewModel.editText.text.toString()

            // Send the request to the API
            mainViewModel.generateText(question)
        }
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun generateText(prompt: String) {
        // Create a logger for debugging purposes
        val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logger)
            .build()

        // Configure the Retrofit object
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.openai.com/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        // Create an instance of the OpenAIService
        val service = retrofit.create(OpenAIService::class.java)

        // Set the request parameters
        val request = mapOf(
            "model" to "text-davinci-003",
            "prompt" to prompt,
            "temperature" to 0,
            "max_tokens" to 182,
            "top_p" to 1,
            "frequency_penalty" to 0,
            "presence_penalty" to 0,
            "stop" to "###"
        )

        // Make the API request
        service.generateText(request = request as Map<String, String>).enqueue(object :
            Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                response: Response<ResponseBody>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseBody = response.body()
                    val responseString = responseBody!!.string()
                    val jsonResponse = JSONObject(responseString)
                    val choices = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0)
                    val text = choices.getString("text")


                    answerText.value = text.trim()

                } else {
                    answerText.value = response.errorBody()?.string()
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                answerText.value = t.message
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**I want to display the answerText.value textview in result fragment. i tried many things but its not showing, I'm just beginner and apologize for bad code or if any errors in code**

I tried to data bind in fragment layout but it shows nothing but printing in log

Comment: You need to observe answerText value in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to observe the answerText object and update the TextView whenever the value changes. Here's an example you can use to display answerText: -

```
class ResultFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var answerText: TextView

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        answerText = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_text)

        // Observe the answerText object and update the TextView whenever the value changes
        answerText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            answerText.text = it
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Could remove redundant SAM-constructor and move the lambda argument outside of parentheses, so answerText.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { answerText.text = it }